# Sorting Selection larger number to the right not completing

Tags: c++, sorting

I am creating a sort selecting that puts the max number to the right. I think i have it mostly done and when i execute the code it works but it does not sort the first two numbers in order from smallest to largest.
When I compile I get 2,1,4,7,9,12,99

```
int n = 7;
    int list[] = { 9, 2, 99, 4, 1, 12, 7};
    int maxIndex = n - 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex-1; i++)
    {
        int maxNum = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (list[j] > list[maxNum])
            {
                maxNum = j;
            }
            int temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[maxNum];
            list[maxNum] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Im not too sure if its the for function or it has to do with the swap that i have but i dont think its the swap or else the it wouldn't order the other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few problems. The first is that your loop limit is incorrect

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex-1; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```

You can get rid of the `maxIndex` variable.

Second your swap is in the wrong place and you swap the wrong elements. You are supposed to swap the maximum value with the current value, so the swap should go **after** the `j` loop and not inside it. It's only after the `j` loop completes that you know what the maximum value is. Plus what you swap is `list[i]` (the current value) with `list[maxNum]` (the maximum value). Like this

```
    int maxNum = i;
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (list[j] > list[maxNum])
        {
            maxNum = j;
        }
    }
    int temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[maxNum];
    list[maxNum] = temp;
```

Incidentally I don't like the variable name `maxNum` because it is not a number it's an index. Maybe `maxNumIndex` would be a better name?

Comment: When make those changes it works but its back words, so it comes out as `99,12,9,7,4,2,1`

Comment: @needusername Then you need to search for the **minimum** element. Replace `>` with `<`.